# difference between emptyList() and EMPTY_LIST android

Tags: java, android, list, collections

Hi all I have been using android's List object when I initialized one of my object as

```
List<Model> model = Collections.emptyList();
```

I get another suggestion which is `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` so I wonder what their differences are.

Thanks!

Comment: `EMPTY_LIST` is the "old way" (pre-Java5). The method does the same thing, but supports generic types (which a field cannot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As type parametrized, `Collections.emptyList()` "guesses" what is a type of your list and you don't get "Unchecked conversion" warning what happens when you just use `Collections.EMPTY_LIST`.

As you can see, they're the same (from sources):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
  return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Watch out, those lists are immutable and always empty.